# How to write a constructor that accepts a single argument?

Tags: c#, winforms, oop, constructor, parallel-arrays

I am creating something like a kiosk program where you order food from using windows forms. I have to create a Toppings Class where it contains three fields that are arrays.

- ToppingList as an array of bool
- ToppingNames as an array of string
- ToppingPrices as an array of double

The instructions say that the constructor must accept a single argument: the length of all three arrays which are parallel arrays.

I am not sure how to do this. I have researched and understand how parallel arrays work but I do not know how to implement and get all three lengths in a single argument. I am not sure if I am doing this correctly?

This is what I have so far:

```
namespace DeliAndPizza
{
    class Toppings
    {
        bool[] ToppingList = { false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false };
        string[] ToppingNames = { "Bacon", "Extra Cheese", "Hot Peppers", "Mayo", "Mushrooms", "Oil", "Onion", "Onion", "Oregano", "Peppers", "Sausage" };
        double[] ToppingPrices = {1.00, 1.50, 0.00, 0.00, 1.00, 0.00, 0.00, 1.00, 0.00, 1.00, 1.00, 0.00 };

        public Toppings()
        {
        }

        public Toppings(bool[] list, string[] name, double[] price)
        {
            this.ToppingList = list;
            this.ToppingNames = name;
            this.ToppingPrices = price;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the given class diagram:

[image: click here]

Comment: What exactly don't you understand in your assignment. It seems you already created a constructor, so why can't you make one with just one argument?

Comment: You say you want the length of all three arrays as a single argument.  It looks like they're all the same length.  So `public Toppings(int length)` would do it.

Comment: Shouldn't the three array be properties? Then simply initialize them to the count given in the constructor (instead of 12 in te declaration)..

Comment: NB: If you wanted to support different lengths, you could make the single argument `int[3] lengths` or define a struct/class with the 3 lengths as properties and pass an instance of that.

Comment: What about using an array of tuples like `Tuple<bool, string, double>[]`?

Comment: What about not messing with their assignment @Fruchtzwerg ;) . Homework is never efficient... And even then, use a class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming all arrays are the same length, you just need to pass the `length` parameter as the single argument to the constructor and initialize the arrays' lengths there, rather than defining the length where you've defined the fields:

```
namespace DeliAndPizza
{
    class Toppings
    {
        bool[] ToppingList;
        string[] ToppingNames;
        double[] ToppingPrices;

        public Toppings(): this(12) {} //default length is 12
        public Toppings(int length)
        {
            ToppingList = new bool[length];
            ToppingNames = new string[length];
            ToppingPrices = new double[length];
        }

        public Toppings(bool[] list, string[] name, double[] price)
        {
            this.ToppingList = list;
            this.ToppingNames = name;
            this.ToppingPrices = price;
        }
    }
}
```

One side note; currently you're using the definitions like `bool[] ToppingList;`.  If you wanted to be able to access this value on an instance of a class (rather than only internally within the class), you'd need to make them public / ideally convert them to properties, like so:

```
public bool[] ToppingList {get;set;}
```

If you don't want them available externally, the naming convention would be to use a lowercase first letter; e.g.

```
bool[] toppingList;
```

[Here's the MS documentation on naming standards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/names-of-type-members#names-of-properties).

The official guide only determines externally visible names; so private fields defined in your class aren't covered by the above doc.  However, [there are conventions](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/76393/69247).